# Export Syntax Coloring for PHP in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, import, export, preferences

I went to:

```
 Window / Preferences / PHP / Syntax Coloring
```

Then made changes to taste, for the workspace I was working on, then I created a new workspace and would like to import those preferences saved at syntax coloring for php as it takes up to an hour to reconfigure to the same preferences all of the colors for the syntax, but can't find how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WORKSPACE_DIR/.metadata./plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.php.ui.prefs
```

If you copy it from one workspace to another one then you will get the same syntax coloring settings in both.